# Is adding a column for reduce sql query a good idea?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am new to database deign.

Somethings I have a [one to many] relationship for php to loading. For example, table `"ForumPost"` and `"ForumPostAttachment"`. Which each of a "post" record can have zero to many "attachment".

While lots of the time `"post"` may have zero `"attachment"`, I wonder the program always wasted a query to select from `"ForumPostAttachment"`, checking whatever a post have attachment. If yes, add the attachment data into a array, but if no there will be no action.

So, if I add a column in `"ForumPost"` called `"hasAttach"` to store a value (may be 0 or 1) .So after select from `"ForumPost"`, I can simply using `"if"` in php, only do the 2nd query f `"hasAttach" == 1`. I think this will save some resources. However, I haven't seen this in examples, and I wonder it is good or stupid, Please give me some advise.

Sorry If this is a  "primarily opinion-based", but any help will be thanks.

---

Edit :

Thanks Nick's comment. one of reason I ask this question is I been told "less query is good". But somehow, is it commons to use extras query to do bunch of checking ?

Comment: IMO, it is best to execute the query to get the attachments. If you put a flag on the "ForumPost" table, you will then have to manage it, meaning a post exists and someone adds an attachment (now you must update the post too) and then they delete the attachment (now you must query the attachments to see if there are other attachments still associated with the post so you can set the flag properly).

Comment: Yes, good point. More important, It is bad when other programmer check the project will takes time to understand what is that doing.

Comment: The other thing is that if you do a LEFT OUTER JOIN from ForumPost to the attachment table, you can do it all in one query, without any need to go back and see whether there is an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a form of *denormalization* - you are introducing a *redundant* copy<sup>1</sup> of data to speed-up the querying.

However, as others have already hinted, you then run the risk of leaving these two copies out of sync, and effectively corrupting the data. And in a concurrent environment, where an independent concurrent transaction may modify the other copy, it is very easy not to be careful and forgo proper concurrency control (such as locking), leading to hard-to-reproduce *race conditions*.

For this reason, the general goal of database design is normalization<sup>2</sup>, not denormalization. Denormalization should be used very carefully and only *after* you have performed **measurements on realistic amounts of data** and concluded it is absolutely necessary performance-wise.

In your case, denormalization is unlikely to be necessary. I suspect direct querying<sup>3</sup> will probably work just fine, assuming [proper indexing / clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

---

*<sup>1</sup> The term "copy" should not be taken too literally in this context. Essentially, whenever you can infer a piece of data from other piece of data you are making a "copy", even if it has a different "shape".*

*<sup>2</sup> I.e. removal of redundancies and in doing so removal of opportunities to corrupt data. In other words: if something can be inferred, it should not be stored.*

*<sup>3</sup> Or LEFT JOIN if you want to handle multiple posts, as already hinted in the comments.*